# List of successfully running smart contract applications that solve a real world problem?

Tags: contract-development, dapps, adoption

I'm still diving into smart contracts and learning the way it works, but what are some **successfully** running smart contracts applications that solve a real world problem? Is there a list of these projects?

When I say successful, I mean something that either generates a profit to sustain itself or an dapp that is widely used with its source code open.

The dapp needs to beable to run on its own interacting with the ethereum blockchain only and no 3rd party service/website. This would also qualify as a successful smart contract application where no one controls it.

Comment: You can check out https://www.stateofthedapps.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the current 2 main sources of ethereum dapps:

- https://www.stateofthedapps.com/
- https://dappradar.com/

Answer (score 3):

I've put it as a comment initially, but I think it answers the question:  https://stateofthedapps.com is a list of various production smart contracts, some with source code.

Answer (score 2):

[Crypto Sportz is one!](https://www.cryptosportz.com)

It's a platform for making bets on sports games. We are fully functional (no ICO) and running successfully on the Ethereum blockchain.

We noticed that there were too many obstacles for traditional sportsbetting: shady bookies, complicated game mechanics, regional restrictions, etc. We solve these issues through simple game formats and leveraging smart contracts. All funds are handled autonomously, including payouts, and nobody can be restricted from entering.

We sustain a modest profit through very low fees attached to each smart contract.

Hopefully this can be a start to the list you're looking for!

Comment: What is it that you need on the Ethereum blockchain that you cannot do with a centralized server? If you app still requires a trusted 3rd party, what is the point of the blockchain in your use case?

Comment: We don't require any third party! Ethereum blockchain allows us to provide the user important benefits: provably fair, we cannot alter the game or tamper with funds, anonymity.

Comment: You are the 3rd party. If you don't exist, how would your system stay up running? How do you provide sports data into your smart contracts? You, being the "main" oracle to feed outside world data in this app is a 3rd party. Answer this, can your system run without you feeding in data into the system or being able to use another outside feed?